# 10GB installed but only 7.8 is shown

Tags: 12.04, memory

I installed 10GB but my 12.04 LTS 64-bit shows only 10GB.
But the swap shows 10GB so I think internally it did find 10GB? I don't remember exactly how Ubunt calculate how much swap needs by default, per memory installed. I would understand if only 9GB is revealed to user, but 7.8?

Idea?

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7975        927       7048          0         38        352
-/+ buffers/cache:        536       7438
Swap:        10228          0      10228
```

Comment: Do you have an integrated video card? With shared memory?

Comment: @uzsolt Hi. I use this P6T board. http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1366/P6T/#specifications.... 

I don't see integrated card mentioned anywhere. I always have a graphic card. I am using NVS 300 right now.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? You created a 10GB partition to install to? Or you mean you have 10GB of RAM and not all of it is shown? Swap by default uses amount of available RAM multiplied by 2.

Comment: Ooops, sorry. So what is 10GB, your RAM or your partition as dobey asked?

Comment: Please give the output of  'free -m'

Comment: @fabricator4 i just did thanks we have 6 slots, and we filled up 5 slots. we left the last one cuz the ram was bad.

Comment: Check if the RAM is fully recognized in BIOS 1st.

Answer (score 0):

OK, 10 GB is an odd number, but now I understand - you've used 5 x 2GB packages because the sixth one was bad.  More than likely you have to fill the slots 2 by 2; the system may not recognise the fifth package because the sixth one is missing.  As Terry Wang said, check how much memory is being recognised in BIOS/Firmware first.

There's a good chance it will only be seeing 8Gb because it can't see the sixth package, so it's disabled that pair of slots.  Also check your motherboard manual regarding valid memory configuration.

More than likely when you get the sixth memory stick replaced and installed it will be able to see all 12Gb